# Let's make this fun(-ish)

Tags: discussion

Since I cannot ask this on the main website because it will not be a question with much value for many readers, I decided to post it here.

**What are the funny/useless/strange/... pieces of code you found in Magento so far?**
Any version is OK. even 2.0.

I'll start with an old one. From ce-1.1. It can even be older I just couldn't check.

In the file `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml` there is this on line 41:

```
<?php if(false): ?>
        <div class="input-box">
        <label for="shipping:email"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
        <input type="text" name="shipping[email]" id="shipping:email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="validate-email required-entry input-text" /></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

It was later (1.4 when the `default` package was changed to `base`) changed to

```
<?php if(false): ?>
    <div class="fields">
        <label for="shipping:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="shipping[email]" id="shipping:email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

[You can also see it here for 1.1](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.1/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml#L41).  [and here for 1.4](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml#L49)
It was removed much later. In 1.7

Let's see how long can we make the list.

Comment: Sigh. I'm probably going to get in trouble now. Let's just say you can find some interesting disparities with judicious use of `diff -wr` and `{.,downloader}/lib/Mage`.

Comment: https://nwdthemes.com/2015/03/23/funny-pieces-of-code-magento/

Answer (score 18):

app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Cart.php:485

```
     * Go ahead, try to understand ]:->
```

Answer (score 14):

just search for @todo, you will find some very funny comments

Comment: Yeah...I specially like the one in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php`: "Temporary moved those $this->getRequest()->getParam('blabla')..."...Sure "temporary". It has been there in 1.1 and it's there in 1.8.

Answer (score 10):

lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:

```
protected function _convertToByte($memoryValue)
{
    if (stripos($memoryValue, 'M') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024 * 1024;
    } elseif (stripos($memoryValue, 'KB') !== false) {
        return (int)$memoryValue * 1024;
    }
    return (int)$memoryValue;
}
```

Guess now, what happens if you set `ini_set('memory_limit', '3G');`?

Comment: Knowing Magento for a bit, that actually is a pretty serious issue, right?

Comment: Can easily result in hours of debugging.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly yes, it can.

Answer (score 9):

When I search for `@FIXME`, I found this text:

```
"stupid fix of previous multi-roles logic".
```

In Magento 1.8.0.

Comment: It's been there since 1.1: https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php#L97

Answer (score 8):

Some `WAT???` from the talk I gave with riconeitzel:

## we should do this ... later

```
# …/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
# Zeile 173
// Todo: put it somewhere in config!
$countOfQueue = 3;
$countOfSubscritions = 20;
```

---

## call array as method

```
# …/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Exception.php
# Zeile 37
protected $_resultCallbackParams = array();

$this->_resultCallbackParams($path, $arguments);
```

---

## where can I find `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Scheduled_Operation`?

```
# …/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
# Zeile 89
$dirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . Mage_ImportExport_Model_Scheduled_Operation::LOG_DIRECTORY
```

hint: `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Scheduled_Operation` never existed in public

---

## `addAttribute` uses shortcuts, `updateAttribute` not!?

`addAtribute` uses `visible` = …
`updateAttribute` uses `is_visible` = …

---

Backend: StoreView ... Store ... Website

Frontend: Store ... StoreGroup ... Website

```
#wtf
```

Comment: I don't know if I should laugh or go 'oh oo' at these.

Answer (score 7):

Not funny, just sad:

[image]

Comment: 92 is not that bad if you count the total number of function and class methods.

Answer (score 6):

Found in `Mage_Api2_Helper_Data`

```
foreach ($adapters as $adapter) {
    if (empty($adapter['enabled'])) {
        unset($adapters);
    }
}
$adapters = (array) $adapters;
```

"Thats what you get for disabling an auth adapter - we'll unset 'em all!"

Answer (score 6):

Just stumbled over the tax discount totals calculation model:

```
    /**
     * Calculate discount tac amount
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
    //        echo 'discount';
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The `tax.phtml` template seems to check if your phone is in airplane mode:

```
<td <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
    <?php if ($this->displayFullSummary() && !$this->getIsPlaneMode()): ?>
        <div class="summary-collapse"><?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->__('Tax'); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

Found in `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`:

```
/**
 * Get quote checkout method
 *
 * @deprecated since 1.4.0.1
 * @return string
 */
public function getCheckoutMehod()
{
    return $this->getCheckoutMethod();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Fixing typos whilst  maintaining backwards compatibility is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $params = array(
        'store_id'      => $store->getId(),
        'locale_code'   => $store->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE),
        'filters'       => $this->_searchQueryFilters
    );
    $params['filters']     = $this->_searchQueryFilters;
```

Comment: What file is this? I couldn't find it in the CE version.

Comment: Let's pretend it's a CE ;) Otherwise I have to delete it.

Comment: ok. Got it...(wink wink)

Answer (score 3):

Found in `Mage_Core_Model_Cache`

```
$content = false;
foreach ($this->_requestProcessors as $processor) {
    $processor = $this->_getProcessor($processor);
    if ($processor) {
        $content = $processor->extractContent($content);
    }
}
```

Like, we treat all request caching processors equal. It would be unfair to break out after the first hit!

Answer (score 3):

I have a *lot* of funny, useless, and/or strange code in my app/code/local.

:D

Comment: Everyone does. :) The most useless/funny/strange code is in community folder. But let's keep it to the core only.

Comment: How about 3rd party modules?  And what if I just move the stuff I have in app/code/local into app/code/core?  :P

Comment: If you want to make enemies, go ahead. But don't post my code in here :). When I asked the question I was thinking of the core modules only, but why not. But it's going to be hard to verify it if you don't specify the source.

Comment: If you still want to show some code from 3rd party modules you can do it here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/288/146

Answer (score 3):

## Math is hard

```
/**
* Using regular rounding. Ex:
* price incl tax   = 52.76
* store tax rate   = 19.6%
* customer tax rate= 19%
*
* price excl tax = 52.76 / 1.196 = 44.11371237 ~ 44.11
* tax = 44.11371237 * 0.19 = 8.381605351 ~ 8.38
* price incl tax = 52.49531773 ~ 52.50 != 52.49
*
* that why we need round prices excluding tax before applying tax
* this calculation is used for showing prices on catalog pages
*/
```

From `Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not so strange, but there is "_initCatagory()" method in Mage_Catalog_CategoryController.

Comment: Of course there is. How else are you going to init the `catagory`? Maybe you can do it like it's done in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category::_getItemsData`.  where `$categoty   = $this->getCategory();` (Notice the variable name).

Comment: Haha, good one :)

Answer (score 2):

How about `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Config::getTotalModels` from the name it sounds promising that it will be full of great code and maybe a few comments to help you understand what it does and how you can use it.

Then you look into it and there is no comments, no coolness and most importantly no code!

```
public function getTotalModels()
{

}
```

Another one that is a bit confusing, maybe I am miss understand what is going on can be found in `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::_processJob`. There is the following comment:

```
/**
though running status is set in tryLockJob we must set it here because the object
was loaded with a pending status and will set it back to pending if we don't set it here
 */
```

But then there is no code that follows? But I did add a [patch](https://github.com/dmanners/MageCronFix/blob/master/cron-running-patch.diff) for this as we get this a lot on projects.

Comment: :D so that's the reason why the crons are triggered multiple times

Answer (score 2):

`\Mage_Core_Model_Translate::getData` looks funny.

Also `Mage_Core_Model_Translate_String` class is extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Nice @phpdoc at `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php`:

```
/**
 * set address street informa
 *
 * @param unknown_type $street
 * @return unknown
 */
public function setStreet($street)
{
    if (is_array($street)) {
        $street = trim(implode("\n", $street));
    }
    $this->setData('street', $street);
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about international zip code validation in javascript?

```
// js/prototype/validation.js:595
['validate-zip-international', 'Please enter a valid zip code.', function(v) {
        //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /(^[A-z0-9]{2,10}([\s]{0,1}|[\-]{0,1})[A-z0-9]{2,10}$)/.test(v);
        return true;
        }],
```

Answer (score 2):

Found in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php`:

```
/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @TODO delete this methods when {^see above^} is done
 * @return string
 */
```

Just awesome :)

Comment: Enter description, then delete? Makes sense :D

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this beauty in *js/calendar/calendar.js*:

```
Calendar.continuation_for_the_fucking_khtml_browser = function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.9.1.0

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Api/UserController.php:142
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php:150

```
//@FIXME: stupid fix of previous multi-roles logic.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Parse .htaccess file and apply php settings to shell script
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, which happens a lot, there is a some odd things going on with the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cache_Grid::_afterLoadCollection`.

```
/**
 * Add name and description to collection elements
 */
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    foreach ($this->_collection as $item) {
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Let's see if I got this right :D
I think this is related to the fact that the collection from that block is an instance of `Varien_Data_Collection` which `implements IteratorAggregate` and you have 
`public function getIterator()
    {
        $this->load();
        return new ArrayIterator($this->_items);
    }`
So I think the foreach does a load on each $item.

Comment: @Emi that's totally apparent by looking at the code (oh wait, jk, it looks like absolutely nothing is happening at all).  Gj magento.. gj..

Answer (score 1):

When getting tier prices there is a spelling mistake for formatted price. Nothing major my phpstorm dictionary complains.

```
$price['formated_price'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($tierPrice);
$price['formated_price_incl_tax'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice(
    Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice(
        Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $price['website_price'], true)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This wonderful typehint in the layered navigation.

```
/** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
```

Comment: it seams that categoty and catagory are real words :) http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/242/146

Comment: @Marius I like the fact that there are two fails in this typehint just to make doubly sure that something that should be useful has no use.

Answer (score 1):

> // log in and send greeting email, then die happy

:))
found in 1.9
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 occurrences of the word `tempate` throughout Magento. Often being mapped to a constant with the correct spelling :)

```
const XML_PATH_CONTENT_TEMPLATE_FILTER = 'global/catalog/content/tempate_filter';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found this horror.

`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::addStockStatusToProducts`

```
/* back compatible stock item */
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $object = new Varien_Object(array('is_in_stock' => $product->getData('is_salable')));
    $product->setStockItem($object);
}
```

Is not compatible with.

`Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty`

```
/* @var $stockItem Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item */
if (!$stockItem instanceof Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The stock item for Product is not valid.'));
}
```

Fails the bloody `instanceof` check.

Answer (score 1):

Found in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`:

```
$heightLimit = 270; //assuming the image is not a "skyscraper"
```

Found in `js/prototype/window.js`:

```
// Fucking IE select issue
WindowUtilities._showSelect(win.getId());
```

Found in `lib/PEAR/HTTP/Request.php`:

```
// magic quotes may fuck up file uploads and chunked response processing
$magicQuotes = ini_get('magic_quotes_runtime');
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mage_SalesRule observer follows some weird naming conventions. Actually none at all, each observer method is named completely differen. But this is my highlight:

```
public function sales_order_afterPlace($observer)
```

the event is `sales_order_place_after`. Who understands this logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
$installer->addAttribute('customer', $disableAGCAttributeCode, array(
    'type'      => 'static',
    'label'     => 'Disable Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID',
    'input'     => 'boolean',
    'backend'   => 'customer/attribute_backend_data_boolean',
    'position'  => 28,
    'required'  => false
));
```

Comment: Interesting; was this every fixed in later version update? app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.0-1.6.2.0.php

Answer (score 0):

// do not add grops without attributes

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php

v1.8

Answer (score 0):

```
* Enter description here...
```

found in Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element :-)

Comment: Isn't this the same as this answer http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/a/246/146 ?

Comment: seems that i haven`t seen that...

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove this next part when we stop supporting that crap-ass PHP 4.2
```

Comment: What file is that? What version?

Comment: Technically not part of magento I suppose as it's in the pearlib downloader/php/pearcmd.php. I was just looking for colourfull langauge, It seems the developer of external libarys swear more than the Magento ones.

e.g calendar.js if (Calendar.is_khtml) setTimeout("Calendar.continuation_for_the_fucking_khtml_browser()", 10);
 else
Calendar.continuation_for_the_fucking_khtml_browser();

and in prototpye/window.js sums up IE.
// Fucking IE select issue

Answer (score 0):

## I am a Hermit

I don't get any visitor:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_SalesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Additional initialization
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setUsedModuleName('Mage_Sales');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('sales');

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales', 'sales');
        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Sales'), $this->__('Sales'));
        $this->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Orders'), $this->__('Orders'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales');
    }
}
```

This is my dwelling:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('sales/index.phtml');
    }

    public function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->assign('createUrl', $this->getUrl('*/sales/new'));
        $this->setChild('grid', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_grid', 'sales.grid'));
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

`sales/index.phtml` is an empty cave and `adminhtml/sales_grid` is a non-entity, which suits me just fine until the day I die.

Answer (score 0):

Those __constructs...
Those underlines on variables...
Those alias non usage...
Those @TODO's (* @todo Needs to be reimplemented to get rid of the copypasted methods)

Was Magento 2 really ready for public???